# Access the previous record to compare the value in DAX POWER BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerpivot

I need to access the previous record of the DTH_REFER_PEDID column to make the IF comparison (`DTH_REFER_PEDID-1 <> "A"`).
That is, I'm reading the index X, I need to compare with the index X-1

[image]

```js
Addition_Stats = VAR Atendido_OV = PR_HIST_MOVIM_PEDID[OVITEM_Hist]
VAR linha_anterior2 = CALCULATE(values(PR_HIST_MOVIM_PEDID[STA_ITEM_PEDCL]);filter(PR_HIST_MOVIM_PEDID;EARLIER(PR_HIST_MOVIM_PEDID[DTH_REFER_PEDID])))      
Return 
                       if(PR_HIST_MOVIM_PEDID[DTH_REFER_PEDID].[Month]<PR_HIST_MOVIM_PEDID[DAT_MAIOR_PLANE].[Month];"Atraso mês ant";
                            if(PR_HIST_MOVIM_PEDID[STA_ITEM_PEDCL] = "A" && PR_HIST_MOVIM_PEDID[DTH_REFER_PEDID].[Day]<=PR_HIST_MOVIM_PEDID[DAT_MAIOR_PLANE].[Day];"Atendido no Prazo";
                                 if((PR_HIST_MOVIM_PEDID[STA_ITEM_PEDCL]="P"||PR_HIST_MOVIM_PEDID[STA_ITEM_PEDCL]="L") && PR_HIST_MOVIM_PEDID[DTH_REFER_PEDID].[Day]<= PR_HIST_MOVIM_PEDID[DAT_MAIOR_PLANE].[Day];"Planejado no prazo";
                                      if(PR_HIST_MOVIM_PEDID[STA_ITEM_PEDCL]<>"A" && PR_HIST_MOVIM_PEDID[DTH_REFER_PEDID].[Day]>PR_HIST_MOVIM_PEDID[DAT_MAIOR_PLANE].[Day];"Em atraso";
                                             if(PR_HIST_MOVIM_PEDID[STA_ITEM_PEDCL] = "A" 
                                                  &&  linha_anterior2 <>"A"
                                                  && PR_HIST_MOVIM_PEDID[DTH_REFER_PEDID].[Day]>PR_HIST_MOVIM_PEDID[DAT_MAIOR_PLANE].[Day];"Atend fora Prazo"
                                               
                                                      ;IF((PR_HIST_MOVIM_PEDID[OVITEM_Hist]=Atendido_OV)&&(PR_HIST_MOVIM_PEDID[DTH_REFER_PEDID]>FIRSTDATE(PR_HIST_MOVIM_PEDID[DTH_REFER_PEDID].[Date]));"A retido";"NA")
                                               )
                                        )
                                    )
                               )
                      )
        
//)
```

The error displayed is: `A circular dependency has been detected: PR_HIST_MOVIM_PEDID [Addition_Stats].`

How do I compare `DTH_REFER_PEDID-1 <> "A"`?

Comment: Do you have Index / date column/s in your model?

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to work with previous or next records is:
Make sure your data is in a table with a primary key (=ID)
Make a query with all the fields as in your table and add one colum with ID+1. (or ID-1)
Make another query with the table and the query mentioned above and make a join between ID and ID+1 (or ID-1). Place all the fields of the table and the 1st query and you end up with all the values in 1 record. This way you can work with the previous or next values.